# Number format in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, formatting, floating-point

What's the best way to format a number?

- If decimal is less than `2` digits, add zero to make it `2` decimals
- If more than `4`, truncate to `4` decimals
- If `3` decimals, keep it to `3` decimals

  ```
  14 => 14.00
  14.1 => 14.10
  14.123 => 14.123
  14.12347 => 14.1234
  ```

**I don't want rounding to happen**

```
if (number !== 0) {
    nParts = number.toString().split('.');
    if (nParts[1]) {
      if (nParts[1].length > 4) {
        nParts = 4;
      } else if (nParts[1].length < 3) {
        nParts = 2;
      } else {
        nParts = 3;
      }
    } else {
      nParts = 2;
    }
} 
number = number.toFixed(nParts);
```

Help me improve on this.

Comment: As I interpret it, 14.99999 → '14.9999'

Comment: toString().split('.') isn't going to work reliably. Consider that some cultures write their numbers using a comma for a decimal `987,24`

Comment: @kleinfreund Right

Comment: @200_success Correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you don't want rounding, treat as string rather than number...

```
function strange(number){
    var n=0;
    if (number !== 0) {
        nParts = number.toString().split(/\.|,/);
        if (nParts[1]){
            n=nParts[1].length;
            n = n <=2 ? 2 : n==3 ? 3 : 4;
            nParts[1] = nParts[1] + '0'
        }else{
            n=2;
            nParts[1]='00';
        }
    } 
    return nParts[0] + '.' + nParts[1].slice(0,n);
}

;strange(14);
;strange(14.1);
;strange(14.123);
;strange(14.12347);

/*
14 => 14.00
14.1 => 14.10
14.123 => 14.123
14.12347 => 14.1234
*/
```